# Как можно реализовать скрипт для работы с языковым интерфейсом в виндовс?

Tags: windows, ос, смена-языка

Я раньше не делал ничего для работы с виндовс, поэтому даже не знаю, где можно посмотреть какие-то инструкции или документацию для языкового интерфейса.

Хочу написать скрипт, который будет работать с языковой панелью, в частности по хоткею добавлять туда новые языки из заранее заданного и скачанного списка и пр. Пытался загуглить, но там что-то похожее сделано только за счет добавления новых хоткеев, а я хочу написать полноценное расширение для языковой панели винды.

Где можно найти информацию об этом, или примеры?

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Вам нужна идея, как это сделать? Или алгоритм, как скрипт написать?

Comment: @Зонтик скорее первое. Мне нужно узнать, через что такие приложения вообще пишутся. В документации микрософта я нашел [информацию по языковой панели](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/win32/tsf/language-bar)), но мне до сих пор непонятно как это можно использовать, мне бы хотелось примера готового приложения или какой-то статьи, где в общем бы раскрывалась работа с языковой панелью